# Converting GeoTIFF to CSV using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, csv

I'd like to covert GeoTIFF to CSV by using QGIS.
How can I do it?

Comment: Each row is a coordinate and a value? Or what do you mean

Comment: Welcome to GISE SR. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here are supposed to demonstrate research and an attempt to solve the task. Please [Edit] the Question to answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?"

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS's Processing Toolbox, do a search for Raster Pixels to Points. That will create a CSV file of each Pixel of a GeoTiff.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I could do that, and  put points. Where can I get a CSV file on QGIS?

Comment: In the Raster Pixels to Points dialogue box you can specify whether you want a Point Shapefile or CSV.